# React Navigation Version 6: How to add header bottom border and change border color?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to add a border to a react navigation header, but nothing is working for me.

Please note, I'm using version 6.

Here are the options I've tried so far:

```
options={{
          headerShadowVisible: true,
          shadowOffset: { height: 0, width: 0 },
          shadowColor: 'red',
          borderBottomColor: 'red',
          borderBottomWidth: 4,   
        }}
```

None of the above options have worked for me.

I have checked the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#options), but I can't find anything.

Comment: Try setting "borderWidth: 1"

Comment: @AlapAnerao appreciate the input but that didn't work either. I'm using version 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no option for native stack you need to use stack navigator

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#options

And you need to send the styles to this param `headerStyle` and not the root of options

Answer (score 5):

**Just add this to add a border in navigator v6 :)**

```
   contentStyle: {
          borderTopColor: colours.primary,
          borderTopWidth: 3,
        },
```

**This is what mine looks like:**

```
<Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="BreaksNavigationScreen"
      screenOptions={{
        statusBarStyle: 'dark',
        headerShown: true,
        headerTintColor: colours.whiteAlways,
        headerTitleStyle: {color: colours.whiteAlways},
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: colours.secondary900,
        },
        headerRight: () => <AppToggleDarkMode />,
        contentStyle: {
          borderTopColor: colours.primary,
          borderTopWidth: 3,
        },
      }}>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can just app screen border with this code :

```
 contentStyle: {
      borderTopColor: colours.primary,
      borderTopWidth: 3,
    },
```

if you have stripe or tiny border color on you header an want to remove that
add

```
  headerShadowVisible: false,
```